# boto3 iot-data published messages not receiving

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-iot

Im trying to publish a message via a python Lambda function to AWS IoT.

I've subscribed to a topic ('test') on the IoT console and triggered the function and the messages aren't getting delivered.

Python Code Snippet:

```
iot = boto3.client('iot-data','eu-west-1') res = {
        "message" : "Hello!"
    }
    iot.publish(
        topic='test', //do we need to pass the thing name here?
        qos=0,
        payload=json.dumps(res))
```

IoT policy:

```
{   "Version": "2012-10-17",   "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }   ] }
```

Also, I have allocated the the correct IAM privileges to the lambda function to publish to IoT.

Any help to pint me at the right direction much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out, my lambda function is deployed within a VPC subnet without a internet connection. Created a NAT gateway and now the subnet getting internet access through it.

P.S- To publish messages to IoT (MQTT) needs an internet connection.